# How to run UFT script without having UFT installed

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I want to know whether is there any way to run script written in UFT without having UFT installed in your PC. 
Can we export Script to some .vbs or .exe file? Or is there any alternate way through which we can execute scripts?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet what your UFT scripts look like? Anything that is reliant on the UFT Framework will not run without UFT installed and licensed.

Answer (score 1):

If you had developed the scripts using Object hierarchy, then you cannot run it without UFT. Scripts having only VBScript commands can be executed as .vbs, but we cannot do activities on Objects then.

But you can run UFT in Remote Desktop by providing it as parameters in 'CreateObject("Quicktest.Application",Remote Ip)'. Other than this, it is not possible to execute a UFT script outside UFT.

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute scripts without UFT installed. That being said, from UFT 12.50 onwards, HP is providing a standalone component called as "Run Time Engine". Here is the snapshot.

The ***HP Unified Functional Testing (UFT) Runtime Engine*** is a core component
of UFT which enables you to run various tests (GUI, API and BPT) in functional 
testing. In previous UFT versions, this feature was only available with the full 
UFT installation. However, beginning with version 12.50, you can use the Runtime Engine as a standalone installation option for your automated testing environment.

[Reference](https://community.hpe.com/t5/All-About-the-Apps/An-in-depth-look-at-the-UFT-Runtime-Engine-in-UFT-12-50/ba-p/6780749)

Answer (score 0):

Definately possible.
UFT has introduced a new feature called LeanFT . It just requires installation of LeanFT jars and requires a method to call them

Answer (score 0):

You now can with the UFT Runtime Engine. More information can be found at [this link](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/latest/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/About_RuntimeEngine.htm).

From that site:

> The UFTRuntime Engine enables you to run UFT tests (both GUI and API)
>   and business process tests on your computer without installing the
>   entire UFT IDE. In addition, you can also install the Runtime Engine
>   without the Run Results Viewer, UFT Add-in for ALM, sample
>   applications, or Help documentation. This can potentially save you
>   valuable disk space on your computer

Answer (score 0):

You need UFT 14 v or above to make it use.
UFT 12 doesn't have that this feature